# Getting the previous sibling of a node using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am currently creating an analyzer using the roslyn sdk. I ran into a case where it was simpler to check child tokens for Wait()/.Result.

The code i am sharing works perfectly fine - However i was unable to find a better way on google nor through browsing the docs.

This way of getting the previous sibling of a node feels very weird - Is there a better way?

```
        if (context.Node is IdentifierNameSyntax identifierName)
        {
            if (identifierName.Identifier.Text == TaskIdentifierWait || identifierName.Identifier.Text == TaskIdentifierResult)
            {
                var siblingsAndSelf = identifierName.Parent.ChildNodes().ToImmutableArray();
                var selfIndex = siblingsAndSelf.LastIndexOf(identifierName);
                if (selfIndex <= 0)
                    return;

                var previousSibling = siblingsAndSelf[selfIndex-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the `ChildNodes` only once with the `Zip` extension where the first collection starts at the first element and the other one at the second element with `Skip(1)`. This will produce tuples with pairs such as `Previous` & `Current`. Now you can filter it and pick at the same time the `Last` element that satisfies the condition:

```
var childNodes = new[] { "a", "a", "b", "c", "a" };

var previousSibling =
    childNodes
        .Zip(childNodes.Skip(1), (p, c) => (Previous: p, Current: c))
        .Last(t => t.Current == "c").Previous; // b
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still iterate twice over childNodes. If I understand Zip correctly, it iterates over both arguments seperately, no matter if if's the same collection. So performance wise there is probably not much of an advantage, though readability is IMHO much less clear.

Comment: @crazy_crank yeah, you're right, it does iterate twice or rather at the same time but without testing you cannot say which way is better especially that the question severly lacks context and I shouldn't even have answerd it in the first place so I VTC - I don't agree or readability because it's much better (unless someone doesn't get linq)

Comment: totally correct. Using your method now in my context anyway. Wanna take back what I said about readillity though, your version is definitily cleaner. I just always find the Zip operator hard to read, but that's probably just because I use it so rarely

Comment: @crazy_crank cool ;-) I think I'll create my own `Zip` that returns a tuple automatically becuase doing `(p, c) => (Previous: p, Current: c)` is such a common task that I wonder it's not already there and writing this every time feels unnecessary.

Comment: for some reason this doesn't let me go^^ Because, what this usage of Zip does is basically creating something resembling a single-linked list. Hence I'm thinking, what would be the disadvantage of using a LinkedList, finding the node and just return the previous nodes value? I actually changed my implementation to `return new LinkedList<SyntaxNode>(node.Parent.ChildNodes()).Find(node).Previous?.Value` (whereas node is the parameter of the GetPreviousSibling(...) method. What do you think?

Comment: @crazy_crank I think you should encapsulate this _ugly_ expression with to extensions: `node.Current()` and `node.Previous()` - now your code is pretty again ;-]

Comment: well, hopefully `node.Current() == node` otherwise I fear I will run into unforeseen troubles :)